# Java syntax for declaring and initialize variables within a while() loops initialization section?

Tags: java, while-loop

Can you declare a variable in the while() loops initialization section, in the same way as you can in a for() loop?

Normally, you can write something like this:

```java
boolean continueProgram = true; 
while (continueProgram){
    // Loop program
    continueProgram = false;
}
```

But i wonder if there is a syntax to write the while() loop the same way as you can do in a for() loop?

A for() loop could look something like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    // Loop program
}
```

Is there a way to declare a variable within a while() loop's condition similar to how it's done in a for() loop?

```java
while (boolean continueProgram = true; continueProgram){
    // Loop program
    continueProgram = false;
}
```

By doing this, the variable would be local to the while() loop only.

Comment: "*Is there a way to declare a variable within a while() loop's condition similar to how it's done in a for() loop?*" - No.

Comment: Why not use a `for` loop then?

Comment: No, it's not possible with while. Use a for loop. And I sure hope the `false` is only assigned conditionally

Comment: In my case, the `false` is assigned conditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the syntax of `while` does not allow this. But you can use a `for` loop: expressions can be empty too:

```
for (boolean continueProgram = true; continueProgram; /* empty */) {
    // Loop program
    continueProgram = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"... Can you declare a variable in the while() loops initialization section, in the same way as you can in a for() loop? ..."*

No.  And, I believe the *[for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)* is the only *control-flow structure* that allows for variable declaration.

> *"... But i wonder if there is a syntax to write the while() loop the same way as you can do in a for() loop? ..."*

Use the *increment [unary operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)*.

```java
int i = 0;
while (i++ < 10){
    // Loop program
}
```

> *"... Is there a way to declare a variable within a while() loop's condition similar to how it's done in a for() loop? ..."*

No, you'll be required to declare each variable before the *loop*.

```java
boolean continueProgram = true;
while (continueProgram){
    // Loop program
    continueProgram = false;
}
```